# How to hide/show toolbar

Tags: interface

How do you hide/show the viewport menu which starts with 'Object' (what mode you are in) and ends with render mode?

Thanks,
Rusty

Comment: Right click on the toolbar > Header > Uncheck "Show Header". To make it appear again click on the downward facing arrow in the top right corner. Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: No. Toolbar is misleading. They're more floating icons in the 3d view that stuff like object mode, view, select, add, object... and so on.